# Domain certificate certbot issue or NGINX and GUNICORN3 do not handle request

Tags: python, nginx, https, dns, gunicorn

I want to post a test Flask SSL server on UBUNTU.
Here is my domain:
viberchatbot.ga
[www.viberchatbot.ga](http://www.viberchatbot.ga)

'A' record propagation is all green for domain and www.domain.

I managed to setup SSL with 'sudo certbot --nginx'

Here are my listeners:
[image: opened ports]

here is the cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask_app:

```
server {
        server_name viberchatbot.ga www.viberchatbot.ga;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/viberchatbot.ga/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/viberchatbot.ga/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot 

}
server {
    if ($host = www.viberchatbot.ga) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = viberchatbot.ga) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        server_name viberchatbot.ga www.viberchatbot.ga;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

and I am trying to access a simple test.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",  debug=True)
```

If I use python3 test.py and inside I have app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000,  debug=True)
I can see the Hello World! at my <external_ip>:5000

It seems I cannot get nginx and gunicorn to communicate or I have an issue with my domain.

I only get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in the browser on both viberchatbot.ga and [www.viberchatbot.ga](http://www.viberchatbot.ga).

*EDIT* Just to add I did follow this:
https://letsdebug.net/www.viberchatbot.ga/1081371

and got the following:
[image: debug]

Maybe I am having some certificate problems?

Edit:
I forgot to mentioned that I unlinked the *default* from nginx/sites-enabled
I have not modified sites-available

Comment: do you have problem to access gunicorn `http://127.0.0.1:8000` ? How do you start `guincorn`?

Comment: @furas, I start gunicorn with `gunicorn3 --workers=3 test:app` no issues with reaching it with curl `curl -il 127.0.0.1:8000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn
Date: Mon, 20 Jun 2022 09:19:53 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 14

Hello, World!
`

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the communication between gunicorn and nginx or with the domain's certificate or records.

Also NGINX was routing to 443 properly.

I had the following open in UFW:

```
ubuntu@vbot-instance:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

However my 443 requests were still being blocked by the firewall.
I disabled/enabled UFW multiple times but no change.

What fixed it was a simple restart of the Ubuntu instance from the Oracle cloud where it was hosted.
I re-launched all the services after the restart and the 'Hello World!' appeared.